# ReactDOM.render has no effect in specific circumstances?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering

I have a method that renders an icon (font-awesome icon) inside provided container. Icon rendering can happen by user clicking on specific `div` or by program itself automatically calling rendering function when it mimics user clicking specific div.

To better understand this. I have created this so called `TicTacToe` game. It is possible to play `player vs player` or `player vs cpu`. If two players are playing then there is no problem, everything is rendered fine.

Now when player plays against CPU, something strange happens. If first player is CPU, then its first move is not rendered (icon does not appear). But the rest appears fine.

And if I make both players to be CPU (CPU plays against another CPU), then nothing gets rendered. Could it be that `ReactDOM.render` ignores changes if they happen too fast?;)

So here is part of the program (game):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    const ICONS_CLASSES = {
        x: 'fa fa-times fa-lg',
        o: 'fa fa-circle-o fa-5x'
    }
    function renderMove(el, turn){
        const classes = ICONS_CLASSES[turn];
        ReactDOM.render(
             React.createElement('span', {'className': classes}),
             el
         )
    }
...
...
});
```

Also here is a function that is called by program itself to mimic clicking on a specific div in a game (well let say CPU "clicks" it):

```
function clickPosition(el, tic){
    if(tic.state == 'running'){
        // Save which player played, because after playing move, it will
        // switch turn for another player.
        const type = tic.turn.type;
        const res = tic.play(el.id);
        if(res != 'invalid')
            renderMove(el, type);
        updateInfo(tic.info)
        // Add start block to be able to play again.
        if(tic.state == 'stopped'){
            // Highlight win combo if there is any
            if(tic.winCombo)
                highlightWin(tic.winCombo)
            toggleEl($('#start'))
        }

    }
}
```

So calling such render as previously said will not render all the time (when playing with CPU).

But if I change that render to this:

```
el.innerHTML = `<span class="${classes}"></span>`;
```

Then it renders any icon just fine. No matter if game is played `player vs player`, `cpu vs player`, `player vs cpu` or even `cpu vs cpu` (in this case all icons are rendered instantly, because the end result is always draw).

Is there some gotcha with `ReactDOM.render`?

P.S. If you are interested, you can find full code here (currently it is enabled to be played `cpu vs player`, meaning first will play CPU. And because it is rendering with `ReactDOM.render`, first move will be invisible. Others should appear fine): https://codepen.io/andriusl/pen/qjyBdB

Answer (score 1):

It looks like everything is OK with `ReactDOM.render`. But I was kind of right with guess about rendering happening too fast. But from another place.

There was a function (that I haven't mentioned in question) which cleared all rendered icons. And it would clear after starting the game. When players are playing, then there is no problem, because clearing does happen later then user clicks a `div`. But when cpu does that, it does much faster, so it plays its turn before clearing up is called and it clears that move icon.

So technically it is rendered, but it is instantly removed, looking like it was never rendered, at least to us humans:)

So fix was to move `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` before `tic.start`. Then it always clears before starting game, not after (or before starting another game).

```
$('#x, #o').on('click', function() {
    const second = {'x': 'o', 'o': 'x'};
    // Clear filled positions if any.
    let positions = document.getElementsByClassName('pos');
    _.each(positions, pos => {
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(pos);
    })
    tic.start(this.id, second[this.id]);
    toggleEl($('#start'));
    updateInfo(tic.info);

})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I ran across your question this morning but didn't have time to really look into it. I must say that you're probably not getting the *best* usage out of react here (using nested components, state, props, react's event listeners and letting react handle the mounting/unmounting), but I did find your approach very interesting (in a good way). :)